# What is the etymology of the word 杜撰（ずさん）?

Tags: etymology

Can this word be derived to original Japanese words or is it maybe, like the kanji might suggest, of Chinese origin?

Answer (score 4):

Taken from [here](http://www.gogen-allguide.com/su/zusan.html):

> 杜撰の「杜」は、中国宋の杜黙（ともく）という詩人を表し、「撰」は詩文を作ることで、杜黙の作った詩は律（詩の様式）に合わないものが多かったという故事に由来するという、中国の「野客叢書（やかくそうしょ）」の説が有力とされる。日本には禅を通じて入ったとされ、古くは「ずざん（づざん）」と言われた。

Translation:

The 杜{ず} of 杜撰{ずさん} represents the poet 杜黙｛ともく} from the Song Dynasty. 撰{さん} represents making poems. The poems made by 杜黙｛ともく} often did not fit the [metre](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metre_%28poetry%29), and this act is thought to be the origin to 杜撰{ずさん}. The explanation in the Chinese 野客叢書{やかくそうしょ} is regarded to be the origin. It is believed that this word came to Japan through Zen Buddhism and used to be ずざん（づざん）.

Also from [here](http://ja.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E6%9D%9C%E6%92%B0):

The excerpt from 野客叢書{やかくそうしょ}:

> 杜默 為詩、多不合律。故言事不合格者為**杜撰**。

and the Japanese translation:

> 杜黙（ともく）は宋の詩人、「撰」は著作することで、杜黙の作る詩に律（作詩の規則）を外れたものが多かったことから、誤まりが多い著作を意味するようになったという。
>   (I'm leaving out the translation into English at is pretty much the same as I explained above.)